# How do I merge multiple drives?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have my built-in nvme ssd, an external 1 TB ssd and an external 500 GB SSD.

Some or many of the files overlap, including .ova VM images, Docker Images, code repos, etc.

I want to merge everything on to the external 1 TB ssd so I get all the unique files there.

Do I use `rsync` with some merge flags to do this, ie. nvme to 1 TB ssd first (here I want to overwrite), then external 500 GB ssd to 1 TB ssd (here I want to skip if file exists on the 1 TB ssd).

What's the best way to do this on Ubuntu 23.04?

Answer (score 2):

There is no best way, because there is no standard rule on how your personal files are organized. You have no other option than explore the current organization of the files, then move and delete to organize the way you want.

Disappointing likely, but that is the basic principle.

In automating parts of the copy/move operations, `rsync` indeed will be highly useful. If there are copies of directory trees on different drives, you will be able to `rsync` from one directory to another to ensure the target directory has all the files of the source, and keeps the files that were not in the source. So probably a first step will be to make sure all files from the other drives make it to the target, as much as possible by syncing similar directory trees. Once all files are in the destination, you may need further manual reorganization.

But again, there is no general receipe, neither a 'best way'  to resolve your individual situation.